# Can I allow Github organization members to invite other members

Tags: git, github, privileges, invite, github-organizations

I have created a Github organization and have invited a small group of members.
In future there will be more than 100 people using this organizations repositories.

**Organization owners** are able to invite new members into the **organization**.
**Team maintainer** are able to invite **organization members** into their **team**.
Since there are more than 100 members, to be invited, a proper solution for invitation would be helpful.

A possible solution would be, making some user owner of the organization to invite people. Ownership is also full administration access.

Can I give some members the privilege to invite other Github members into the organization without giving them full administrative access?

Answer (score 0):

I believe that's not possible. You can't set different permissions to collaborators.

Perhaps you should use a different approach. Like giving everyone read permission and use a workflow like [this one](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Distributed-Git-Distributed-Workflows#Integration-Manager-Workflow)

Answer (score 0):

As long as I researched and tried it,**owners cannot give only the privilege of inviting new members to current members**. To enable current members to invite new members, **owners need to give the owner privilege which is full privilege to current members**.